# R moveStack function (move package) shows error "Error: 'same.crs' is not an exported object from 'namespace:terra'"

Tags: r, error-handling, gps, move

I create a move object from a dataframe with gps data from birds. I then split this large MoveStack into a list, producing a list of elements, one for each bird individual (Formal class 'Move'). When I try to bind this list into a df again, I get the following error and warnings:

```
Error: 'same.crs' is not an exported object from 'namespace:terra'
In addition: There were 21 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warnmeldungen:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output; in tests, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/CRS_warnings.html
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output; in tests, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/CRS_warnings.html
3: ...
```

I did exactly the same some month ago – same script and data – and it worked perfectly fine.

I re-installed the move package and lubridate. R Version 4.2.1.  Data and script worked fine couple of month ago.
My code:

```
data2<- as.data.frame(data)
 WGS<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
 data.move <- move(x=data$location.long,
                   y=data$location.lat,
                   time=data$timestamp,
                   data=data,
                   proj=WGS,
                   animal=data$individual,
                   sensor="gps")

 data.clean<-split(data.move)
 # some manipulation on "data.clean"
 data.stack<-moveStack(data.clean, forceTz="UTC")  # creates error
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. `move` had some changes in the last 3~4 months. Re-install or install `terra`, [move - code equalProj](https://gitlab.com/bartk/move/-/blob/master/R/equalProj.R?ref_type=heads), where the error is thrown while evaluating the possible members of a moveStack [line 38](https://gitlab.com/bartk/move/-/blob/master/R/moveStack.R?ref_type=heads), so somewhere in your data cleaning pipeline, CRS got mangled. `packageVersion('terra') [1] ‘1.7.60’`